# Data Augmentation according to sample class TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working on image classification with **Tensorflow**. As input pipeline I'm using `tf.data.Dataset` feeded from `TFRecords`. I'm applying data augmentation using `.map()`. I would like to know if there is a means of applying different data augmentations depending on the label of the image. Let's say: if the image is of class *Person* I'd like to apply a random horizontal flip, but if the image is of class *Background* I'd like to apply a random rotation.

Thanks!

Comment: hi, can u please share snippet of the code. I'm trying to add data augmentation options to the pipeline config on the fly, but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, take note that your tf.data.Dataset pipeline contains both your data **and** labels. Create yourself another `.map()` function just as you've done. It should receive the data and labels, and in there you can use `tf.cond` to either apply the transformation or not apply it depending on the class of the label. Note that you can also transform your label if necessary (it's probably not necessary in the case of classification, but if you had bounding boxes they would need to flip too, for example).

Comment: Thanks David! I was using was using regular conditional instead of `tf.cond`. Now it is working as expected.

Comment: A very common error, you're in good company. :)  Please do mark it as answered if it's done.